# Why does the map $x^2$ have constant rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I'm just trying to wrap my head around the rank of a map via some examples. Now, if I have the smooth map of manifolds $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, F(p) = p^2$, then the differential is given by $dF_p=2p$. When $p \neq 0, dF_p$ has constant rank $1$, but at the point $p=0$ doesn't $dF_p$ have rank $0$ since it's the zero linear map from $T_0\mathbb{R} \to T_0\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Well, you just proved that $x\longmapsto x^2$ does not have constant rank.

Comment: You're absolutely right, your map $F$ has rank $2$ except at the point $p=0$, where it has rank $0$. This is not at all an unusual situation. Indeed, the specification of rotations by Euler angles yields a map $\mathbb{T}^3 \to SO(3)$ whose rank drops from $3$ to $2$ at certain points, which can be physically interpreted as the phenomenon of gimbal lock (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock).